# Do I have the right understanding of Hume's suggested association of ideas?

Tags: hume, idea

Hume, in his Treatise of Human Nature says: "two objects are connected together in the imagination, not only when the one is immediately resembling, contiguous to, or the cause of the other, but also when there is interposed betwixt them a third object, which bears to both of them any of these relations".

Does this mean that, for example, if I living in New York, have qualified for Boston marathon, then while visiting Boston went to a unique restaurant, let's call it "Hume's Pub", will always associate Boston with Hume's Pub by means of this interposition of "running marathon" idea between Boston and the pub?

Comment: Maybe a less convoluted example: a black triangle is associated with a white circle if between them there is a black circle. One pair shares a color and the other a shape.